# Value difference between two pointers is not making sense

Tags: c, pointer-arithmetic

I'm not getting the output. Why it is happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int a[3][3];
    int *p, *q;
    p=a[0];
    q=a[1];
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(int));
    printf("%d\n",q-p);

    printf("%d %d\n",q,p);
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
4
3
2686728 2686716
```

I thought `(q-p)` should be `12`! Is my math degrading?!

Comment: Enable compiler warnings, you're assigning `int`s to pointers and doing (integer) arithmetic on 2 unrelated pointers. Also, your array is not initialsed, so `a[0]` and `a[1]` have unspecified values.

Comment: According to pointer arithmetic this is correct. Check **Differencing**, which is subtraction of two pointers.

Comment: @Ani care to explain why?

Comment: It shows the difference in units of the base type (`int`).

Comment: @juanchopanza: Why `q-p` should be `12`?

Comment: It is 12 if you're talking about bytes, but your talking about ints so 3*sizeof(int) is 12.

Comment: Maybe I'm just extremely rusty at C, but if the OP did this, p=&a[0] and q=&a[1]. Where multidimensional arrays in c are contiguous by the rows i.e. a[0][0],a[0][1],a[0][2],a[1][0]. Therfore q would be ahead of p by exactly 3 ints. And when doing pointer arithmetic it's going to move the pointer by the base type and this holds p + 3 = q. When doing q - p you get 3. But the OP was expecting it to be 12. Thats because the base units were in ints and not chars. If he did this printf("%d\n",(char*)q-(char*)p); he would get 12

Comment: You can see this when the stack address of the pointers are printed, they are exactly 12 bytes apart or 3*sizeof(int).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I thought (q-p) should be 12

No. `(q-p)==3` shall hold true since they have type `int*`. Meanwhile it's true that `q == p + 3`.
Also this is true: `(char*)q - (char*)p == 12`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting output value as `3`, because both pointers are pointing to integer data type and the difference between them is three objects.